# ExtJS and simple grid panel

Tags: extjs

I have a simple grid without direct connection with any database table. Just days of mounth in raws and persons in columns (let's say 31 x 20). In init procedures I read data from some tables, calculate and write them to this grid. Then I have to calculate lot of indexes, make some summs by raws, columns and part of them. Just statistics.

There's no problem with read from grid cells, this is very quick. I have a problem with writing data to the cells. E.g. procedure to fill this grid is the following:

```
days = Ext.getStore('StoreDays').getRange();
employees = Ext.getStore('StoreTeam').getRange();
Ext.each(days, function (day) {
    Ext.each(persons, function (guy) {
        tmp = day.get('from');
        day.set('start_' + persons.data.prs_numer, start);

        ... and 4 additional SET operations to grid cells
    });
});
```

And this procedure work more then 3 minutes!!! I don't know why and how to write good code to write this data normally. Be so kind and prompt me HOW!
Additionally I can't refresh e.g. every single raw after raw settings as I want.
Would you be so kind as to prompt me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell update could mean the grid needs to refresh itself, so it does that 31x20x5 (31 rows, 20 columns, 5 times per cell) times!

Instead, do this:

```
store.suspendEvents();
// Do your update
store.resumeEvents();
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it isn’t solution of my problem.  Time is still the same.
And, this grid is prepared with celledit plugin to let user correct some cells. There is also listetener for with ‘beforedit’ and ‘afteredit’ events. I set break points in this evets and I know this events are not used when program makes my two loops.
When I used debugger I see browser “hangs” for this 3 minutes.

Comment: Then I suggest you post a working test case, otherwise I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for info, I can post it but this application is a part of biger system, so it will be problem to run it without environment and database. I can try to prepare this part of application with problematic grid and let it run on some static data. Right?

Comment: Something that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In the mean time I found solution. It isn't problem of store it is problem of layout. When I set:   Ext.suspendLayouts() before loop and Ext.resumeLayouts(true) after and then grid refresh - time is 3 seconds. But still don't know (browser die for this time, before 5 minutes now 3 seconds) how to e.g. display every new cell in such a loop.